# How to make a package in Ada a generic package?

Tags: package, ada

I have an Ada program to calculate the average and standard deviation of 200 values taken from a file, and they are both working correctly. these packages are in float type, How to turn them into generic type?

The average package ads file is:

```
with Text_IO;
package avg is
  type int_array is Array (1..200) of integer;
  function avrage (ParArray: int_array) return float;
end avg;
```

and the average package body is:

```
with Text_IO;   
WITH Ada.Integer_Text_IO; USE Ada.Integer_Text_IO;
package body avg is
 function avrage (ParArray: int_array) return float is
  result: float :=0.0;
  final:float :=0.0;
  myarray: int_array:=ParArray;
 begin
  for v in myarray'Range loop
     result:= result + float(myarray(v));
  end loop;
  final:=result/200.0;
  return final;
 end avrage;
end avg;
```

I call this package in my main program by "with" and "use". please tell me what to do

Comment: Why do you have `with Text_IO;` when you don't refer to anything declared in `Text_IO`?

Comment: Why do you use `avg` and `avrage`? Why not use `Average` and `Mean` (or perhaps `Statistics` and `Mean`)? And why do you copy `ParArray` to `myarray`?

Comment: because I I've been told that I cannot modify the parameter array, so I've just made a local array in the function and made it return the local array. @SimonWright

Comment: I did that out of Habit. @KeithThompson

Comment: You don't *need* to modify the parameter array. `float Sum = 0.0; for I in ParArray'Range loop Sum := Sum + Float(ParArray(i)); end loop; return Sum / ParArray'Length;`

Comment: Correcting previous comment: Incidentally, making Int_Array an unconstrained array type would make this much more flexible and useful. Realistically someone using your package isn't always going to have exactly 200 elements.

Comment: @ajb: I've posted a corrected comment and deleted the old one. Feel free to delete yours, and I'll delete this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don’t say what you want your package to be generic *in*.

I’m assuming that you want the input to be an array (`Input_Values` below) of some type `Input_Value` indexed by `Input_Index`, and you want the output to be of some floating-point type `Result_Value`. You’ll need a function `To_Result_Value` to convert `Input_Value` to `Result_Value`.

```
generic
   type Input_Value is private;
   type Input_Index is (<>);
   type Input_Values is array (Input_Index range <>) of Input_Value;
   type Result_Value is digits <>;
   with function To_Result_Value (X : Input_Value) return Result_Value;
package Statistics is
   function Mean (Input : Input_Values) return Result_Value;
end Statistics;
```

... with implementation:

```
package body Statistics is
   function Mean (Input : Input_Values) return Result_Value is
      Sum : Result_Value := 0.0;
   begin
      for I of Input loop
         Sum := Sum + To_Result_Value (I);
      end loop;
      return Sum / Result_Value (Input’Length);
   end Mean;
end Statistics;
```

... and a little demo:

```
with Ada.Text_IO;
with Statistics;
procedure Demo is
   type Arr is array (Integer range <>) of Integer;
   function To_Float (X : Integer) return Float is
   begin
      return Float (X);
   end To_Float;
   package Avg is new Statistics (Input_Value => Integer,
                                  Input_Index => Integer,
                                  Input_Values => Arr,
                                  Result_Value => Float,
                                  To_Result_Value => To_Float);
   A : Arr := (1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
   M : Float;
begin
   M := Avg.Mean (A);
   Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line ("mean is " & Float'Image (M));
end Demo;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, what you did is PERFECT. do you know any good textbooks about ADA?

Comment: This is not generic enough, I need to be able to insert a float/Integer and be able to get float/Integer in the output. I have tried changing the To_Float function and the package initiation, but I'm getting an error that says expect float type in instantiation of "Result_Value" you made Result_Vlaue type digit, can I make it Private?

Comment: You *could* make `Result_Value` `private`, but then you’d have to add generic parameters for `”+”`, `”/“`, the initial (zero) value for the summation, and a conversion from `Integer` to `Result_Value` (to convert `Input’Length`). And, if `Result_Value` is an integer type, I’d have thought you’d have problems with rounding/truncation when you divide by the input array’s length? You could always produce a floating-point result and have the caller do the conversion to the required type, which would give them much more control. See [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wn2579wrqxun1l0/statistics.ada).

Comment: See the [AdaIC site](http://www.adaic.org/learn/materials/) for learning material, including some e-books (no Ada 2012 books yet, but the 2005/95 books are still relevant).